# Syntax error with mysql insert from one database to another

Tags: mysql

I keep getting a syntax error with the following mysql statement.  What's wrong??

```
INSERT INTO database1.tbl_user (email) VALUE (SELECT email FROM database2.tbl_user);
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO tablename(fields) SELECT`, drop the `VALUE()` thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrikken wrote:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(fields) SELECT, drop the VALUE() thing.
```